# Sin efecto de animación de un Loader en CSS

Tags: html, css

cree en **CSS** un `loader` la cuan la animación que le puse no se ejecuta (en cual debe de estar girando la parte azul de mi cargador de forma circular), por lo que les pido ayuda para saber cual es el error y bueno les paso el código:

```css
*,*::after, *::before{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contenedor{
  background-color: rgba(250, 240, 245, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#carga{
  border: 15px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-top-style: groove;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@@keyframes girar {
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="carga">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sobra una arroba en `keyframes`:

```css
*,*::after, *::before{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contenedor{
  background-color: rgba(250, 240, 245, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#carga{
  border: 15px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-top-style: groove;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes girar {
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="carga">
  </div>
</div>
```